# Switching between two views in a UIviewController

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller, ios6

The implemented solution worked fine in IOS4, but now in IOS6 it refuses to display the assigned view (I only see the window on screen).

I got a ViewController called MainController. It got two IBOutlets of type UIView. One called portraitView and one called landscapeView.

In the MainController viewWillAppear I assign the view to be the portraitView.

```
self.view = portraitView;
```

Then the orientation changes I assign the view to be the landscapeView.

My problem is that none of the views seems to applear after assigning them to the viewControllers view. As stated, this worked fine in previous versions of IOS.

I have double checked that somehow the views possition haven't changed, and that the alpha and hidden property is correct. The outlets are also bound to the xib objects.

Anybody got a clue to what could be wrong? Adding that my xib file is not built up around a story board, but rather the "old" ibuilder setup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am a little embarresed now. Turned out I had forgotten to @syntezise my view outlets. That caused the views autorelease and not show up in my main controller.

I have no idea why it worked prior to IOS6.

Answer (score 1):

From UIViewController documentation:

```
shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:
Returns a Boolean value indicating whether the view controller supports the specified orientation. (Deprecated in iOS 6.0. Override the supportedInterfaceOrientations and preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation methods instead.)
```

If you're using shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation to know when the rotation occurs, you may need to read up on the way autorotation works now in iOS6.

Comment: The problem is not to get the view to switch between the views, but to get the view to show at all.

Answer (score 0):

I think that viewWillAppear is probably too late in the process to set the view. Try doing it in either the contoller's init method or in viewDidLoad and see if that works.

However, you might want to check out the "Creating an Alternate Landscape Interface" section in the View Controller Programming Guide in the Apple docs for another way to do this.

Comment: I do not think the timing for setting the view is the problem where. I used to replace the view controllers view runtime in different circumstances (button events and such). I did however try to set the viewControllers view both in viewdidload and awakefrom nib. No change. I have also tried to just keep the view from the nib file and use [self.view addSubView:portraitView]. Even if I do this the view will not appear.

Comment: Have you logged portraitView to make sure it's not nil?

Comment: Yes. It is not nil, and i am able to add subviews to it. But they does not show either.

Comment: @Øystein, I can't think of what you problem is without seeing some code. How are you loading the views from the xib files?

Comment: Yea, not that easy to show the code as it is contains in both code and xib files and also consist of hundreds of lines with code. The view is loaded through a class MainController which is a UIViewController. The MainController is setup as the first view in a UINavigationController. The navigation controller is then again setup as the rootController to the applications window. I think I will try to build this setup from scratch having xcode generate a new xib file, as the original one dates back to IOS3. Might be some quirk in the file that breaks the view..